# Joomla Website button is putting hastag in url and not working (Joomshaper)

Tags: button, caching, joomla

My website's cookie policy button and mobile menu icon becomes not clickable when its clicked already once. I think there is some kind of cache issue. Also the button click puts hashtag in the url. website is bankonsocial co za. Can anybody help?

Comment: You might want to ask on the Stack Exchange site dedicated to Joomla, [joomls.se]

Comment: Typo in Elin's `[shortcode]`.  Should have been [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.